# Unable to add to ActiveWindow.SelectedWorksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the code

```
Worksheet.Select Replace:=False
```

It does not add to `ActiveWindow.SelectedWorksheets`

The following does not work in all environments.

```
For i = 2 To ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(i).Select Replace:=False
Next i

ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.PrintPreview
```

The print preview only shows 1 page (*first/active sheet*). If I request the Count, its also 1, but I got more then 1 worksheet (*actually more then 10*)

It does look like it has something to do with a windows update (since user experience it suddenly without any change to the macro).

Does anyone expiriance the same issue lately?

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: If you think it have to de with events, you could try do add a `DoEvents` right after your loop

Comment: just tested on Xl2010. No issues ...

Comment: Are you sure the `ActiveWorkbook` is the one you think is actually active? Maybe you would like to try `ThisWorkbook` instead of  `ActiveWorkbook`?

Comment: Also ensure that the sheets contains some text. Any sheet(s) which is empty will not show in the PrintPreview

Comment: It does also work on my machine. Not on some other clients (wich i can't access right now). It did always work fine, but i wil give the ThisWorkbook option a try.

On the other hand, When i loop through them using the debugger, it does find the worksheets, it just does not add them to the SelectedSheets property. All sheets also contain text. The pages do show when choosing "print" from the menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem was reported by one of our workbooks by a user but did not show up on my machine until after I installed the most recent update. It appeared the problem was with the Replace:=False. Original is below.

```
Worksheets("Proposal").Select Replace:=False
Worksheets("Terms").Select Replace:=False
Worksheets("Soft Maint").Select Replace:=False
Worksheets("Emerg Servi").Select Replace:=False
Worksheets("Spl Prov").Select Replace:=False
Worksheets("Equip List").Select Replace:=False
If Application.Sum(Worksheets("Quote Info").Range("B23")) = 1 Then Sheets("FA T&I").Select Replace:=False
If Application.Sum(Worksheets("Quote Info").Range("B23")) = 2 Then Sheets("FA T&M").Select Replace:=False
```

After many tries I came up with this and it worked. Not sure why but I am not the sharpest knife in the drawer. I only changed the first few lines but figured I would past the entire thing in case it helps.

```
Sheets(Array("Proposal", "Terms", "Soft Maint", "Emerg Servi", "Spl Prov", "Equip List")). _
    Select Replace:=False
If Application.Sum(Worksheets("Quote Info").Range("B23")) = 1 Then Sheets("FA T&I").Select Replace:=False
If Application.Sum(Worksheets("Quote Info").Range("B23")) = 2 Then Sheets("FA T&M").Select Replace:=False
```

Hope this helps

Comment: For the sake of clarity, you might as well edit your answer to only include the lines that changed.

Comment: I'll accept this answer because when using the print button it does work.

Also it does show it has more then one page. To actually see the next page, it is not enough to scroll to is or click on the next page button. I also need to zoom in/out to see the preview of the page.

Looks like MS just introduced a bug.

Comment: Oops... My bad. This actualy works just great. I only forgot to re-enable screenupdating (Application.ScreenUpdating = True) before showing the printpreview.